# Installed PHP I need to Get write the timezone

Tags: server, php, timezone

I have a problem regarding the timezone in Ubuntu. It's asking for the timezone and I don't know what to do.

[image: help me out to get the timezone]

Comment: It seems you're using an Android device. How did you install Ubuntu in that? AFAIK Ubuntu isn't availabel officially as an application for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command as sudo user:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone your_time_zone
```

For example, to change the system's timezone to Asia/Calcutta:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Calcutta
```

Run the timedatectl command to verify the changes:

```
timedatectl

           Local time: Thu 2019-01-24 00:27:43 CET
           Universal time: Wed 2019-01-23 23:27:43 UTC
           RTC time: Wed 2019-01-23 23:27:44
           Time zone: Asia/Calcutta
System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
```

OR

You can change timezone to modify `php.ini` file.
Open the php. ini file and go to `;date.timezone =`

Uncomment this line and modify it

```
date. timezone=time_zone
```

Example:

```
date. timezone=Asia/Kolkata
```

Change the default timezone settings by adding your new timezone by modifying this line: `date. timezone=Asia/Kolkata`
Save it and Restart the Apache server.